# C++ Forward Declaration of Overloaded Operators

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, forward-declaration

I found a question on a forum, and I decided to write a quick code. I decided to take the opportunity to teach myself about overloading comparison operators. Unfortunately, I seem to have made a mistake.

I'm trying to compare to `Line` objects inside the `Quadrilateral` class. I keep getting an error that `Line` is an invalid operand for the binary operator `<`. I tried forward declaring the overloaded operator, but that did not seem to help. Can anyone suggest a reason why the comparison is not working? Any help is much appreciated :)

(The overloaded operator function is the last function in the code. The actual comparison occurs in the `Quadrilateral` class)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

class Point {
private:
  int x, y;
public:
  Point(): x(0), y(0) {}
  Point(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {}

  int getX() const { return x; }
  int getY() const { return y; }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Point& pt);

};

class Line {
private:
  Point pt1, pt2;
public:
  Line(): pt1(0,0), pt2(0,1) {}
  Line(const Point& pt1, const Point& pt2): pt1(pt1), pt2(pt2) {}

  friend auto operator<(const Line& ln1, const Line& ln2) -> bool;

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Line& ln);
};

class Quadrilateral {
private:
  Point pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4;
public:
  Quadrilateral(): pt1(0,0), pt2(0,1), pt3(1,0), pt4(1,1) {}
  Quadrilateral(const Point& pt1, const Point& pt2,
                const Point& pt3, const Point& pt4): pt1(pt1), pt2(pt2),
                                                     pt3(pt3), pt4(pt4) {}

  auto getAllLines() const -> std::vector<Line> {
    std::vector<Line> quadLines;
    Line l1(pt1,pt2), l2(pt2,pt3), l3(pt3,pt4), l4(pt4,pt1);
    quadLines.push_back(l1); quadLines.push_back(l2);
    quadLines.push_back(l3); quadLines.push_back(l4);
    return quadLines;
  }

  auto longestSide() const -> Line {
    Line l1(pt1,pt2), l2(pt2,pt3), l3(pt3,pt4), l4(pt4,pt1);
    return (l1 > l2 ? l1 : l2);
  }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Quadrilateral& q);

};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Point& pt) {
  stream << "(" << pt.x << ", " << pt.y << ")";
  return stream;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Line& ln) {
  stream << ln.pt1 << " <-> " << ln.pt2 << std::endl;;
  return stream;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Quadrilateral& q) {
  stream << q.pt1 << "\t" << " <-> " << "\t" << q.pt2 << "\n"
     << "  ^" << "\t" << "\t" << "  ^" << "\n"
     << "  |" << "\t" << "\t" << "  |" << "\n"
     << "  v" << "\t" << "\t" << "  v" << "\n"
     << q.pt4 << "\t" << " <-> " << "\t" << q.pt4 << "\n"
     << std::endl;
  return stream;
}

auto operator<(const Line& ln1, const Line& ln2) -> bool {
  double ln1_len = sqrt( pow((ln1.pt1.getX() - ln1.pt2.getX()),2) - pow((ln1.pt1.getY() - ln1.pt2.getY()),2) );
  double ln2_len = sqrt( pow((ln2.pt1.getX() - ln2.pt2.getX()),2) - pow((ln2.pt1.getY() - ln2.pt2.getY()),2) );
  return ln1_len < ln2_len;
}
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: Two asides: 1) I don't find it intuitive that `<` would compare the *lengths* of two lines. 2) If you are going to compare lengths, no need to take the square roots. (Assuming everything is +ve), you can just compare the sum of the squares and save some expensive operations.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Yes, you're definitely right. I'm just tired and my brain reverted to the second grade where the distance function was all the rage. :)

Comment: that's a kind of a minimal example ... ;)

Comment: I have no idea why you would use trailing return types for something like `bool` or `Line`.

Comment: @T.C.There is no logic behind it. It's actually the *wrong* way to do it. I was just having fun and didn't want to change my code before posting it.

Comment: @T.C. And by wrong, I mean there is no benefit and it makes the code less readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `return (l1 > l2 ? l1 : l2);` causes the error. Note that you are using `>` here, but you have only defined `operator<()`.

Comment: Hahaha! Wow, thanks... My eyes are drooping, should have spotted that, but I can't sleep until I solve it. Thanks :)